# Facebook Checkins on Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that has users regularly checking in to with Facebook. I want to display the currently checked in users (name & avatar) on the homepage. I've managed to achieve this for people checking in with foursquare but can't work out how to do it with Facebook.

As far as I can tell checkins are extended permissions and require an access token. I've managed to generate an Access token using...

```
echo $token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[-APP ID-]&client_secret=[-APP SECRET-]&grant_type=client_credentials');
```

and appending the result to a checking request...

```
echo file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/[-PAGE ID-]/checkins/?'.$token);
```

but all I get from that is:

**400 Bad Request**

I don't want visitors to the site to have to login to facebook & grant permissions to see checked in users... I just want to list account names and pictures.

Is this possible or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not allow you to see the checkins to a place unless the current user is friends with the person checked in.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[-PAGE ID-]/checkins/?access_token=$token
```

will give you all the current users friends who have checked into `[-PAGE ID-]`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/[-PAGE ID-]/checkins/?access_token='.$token);
```

You forgot `?access_token=`

Comment: Unfortunately no, the first response includes the access_token parameter.

Comment: No, I meant on your second code, the "question-mark access_token equals" is missing.